# If $\lim (S_n)=s$, does it follow that $\lim (S_{n+1}) = \lim (S_{n+2}) = s$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have proven $\lim (S_n)=s$, where $S_n$ is a sequence. Am I allowed to say $\lim (S_n) = \lim (S_{n+1}) = \lim (S_{n+2}) = s$?

Comment: Just write \lim S_n between $\$ $'s to get $\lim S_n.$

Comment: yeah, it's just like for regular sequences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can say that. Given $i, j \in \Bbb{N}$ and a series $\{S_n\}$ that converges to $S$, then $$\lim_{n \to \infty} S_{n+i} = S$$ and $$\lim_{n \to \infty} S_{n+j} = S$$ so $$\lim_{n \to \infty} S_{n+i} = \lim_{n \to \infty} S_{n+j}$$